# Receive alert when a JSON Data Object is added

Tags: json

Can anyone think of a way to get alerted when a new JSON Object is added to a publically accessible JSON URL?

If it were you, how would you go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 principle models allowing to get notified on changed: push and pull model.

1. for the push model, a resource owning the object (in this case a site hosting the URL) supposed to provide a subscription mechanism.
2. if push model is unavailable you then default to pull model: this requires polling the resource on your end - you need to come up the scripted way of doing it on your local side.
   Then the basic pseudo would be like:

   - poll JSON object (via REST)
   - compare pulled JSON with preserved one
   - if JSONs are the same: sleep for some time and repeat
   - else: save pulled JSON, send notification and repeat